# Behavior of ANSI escape codes when mixing background and foreground

Tags: terminal, escape-characters, xfce4-terminal, ansi

I'm investigating once more my ANSI escape rendering scripts and I've found weird behavior.
The output color is defined by background or foreground by both mixed together.

Example:

```
echo -e "\x1b[1;30;47m█████▀\x1b[0m"
# or
printf "\33[1;30;47m█████▀\33[0m\n"
```

it's a light gray and darker gray, even that the ANSI codes are bold black and white.
If I remove white (47) I get black foreground, so it's kind of blending two colors 30 and 47 together.

First of all, am I right, is this some kind of blending of colors? Is this behavior some kind of documented and explained in detail and every possible color how to blend two colors? Does it happen for all colors or only black & white?

The reason why this is maybe the case is that I have a perfectly fine script for generating ANSI artwork but it's somehow broken for white or gray colors. The code is created based on Wikipedia articles, other similar resources, and also answers on this Q&A that help a lot.

EDIT:

This is not duplicate, I'm asking about behavior that colors and background mixing have 3 states, one both (BG and FG) apply or either one applies. I'm asking if this is documented somewhere because it seems that this is how ANSI Artwork is rendered. An example is this one:

https://16colo.rs/pack/blocktronics_miracle_on_67th_street/misfit-blocked.ans

That renders fine in XFCe terminal but fails to render properly in my code.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I use bash echo and XFCe terminal. And I'm testing this ANSI artwork https://16colo.rs/pack/blocktronics_miracle_on_67th_street/misfit-blocked.ans I'm not able to render the "#67 DEC" properly in my code.

Comment: @ThomasDickey no it don't answer my question, I'm not asking about the difference in terminal emulators, I'm asking about 3 states that can happen when using combination of background foreground and bold flag. This must be standarized somehow because this how it works for ANSI Art, but it's not documented at Wikipedia article about ANSI escape codes.

Comment: Don't look at the accepted answer. Look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93814/cant-apply-brightness-to-terminals-background-color/93818#93818